# How many 5-digit numbers have distinct digits and are divisible by 3?

Tags: divisibility, number-systems

**Problem:** How many 5-digit numbers have distinct digits and are divisible by 3?

**My direction:** I have tried to find all numbers with 5 digits that are divisible by 3 (30000 numbers) and then I will subtract from it numbers that do not have 5 distinct digits but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you mean you need to find the number of $5$-digit numbers with distinct digits and are divisible by $3$?

Comment: @player3236 Yes, this is my the problem I want to ask. Sorry for my bad expression.

Comment: @lulu I have edited the problem. Sorry for my bad expression.

Comment: Got it,  Might help to note that if you have found one such then any permutation is another example.  The fact that you can't start your string with $0$ causes some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first consider how many numbers there are between $10 \, 000$ and $99 \, 999$ such that all of the digits are distinct. The first digit is between $1$ and $9$, so there are $9$ possible choices. Then, there are $9$ choices for the second digit, $8$ choices for the third digit, etc.

Comment: How does this help with the divisibility condition?

Comment: @player3236 It doesn't. My suggestion is to first consider how many numbers there are with distinct digits, and then to narrow it down from there. I think doing it the other way round might be trickier.